# Why does 'tree' command ignore directories but not files

Tags: tree

`tree` shows

```
...
│   ├── template_one_file.sh
│   ├── template_sed.sh
│   ├── testy.sh
│   ├── tmp
│   │   ├── file1.html.13567_old
│   │   ├── file2.html.13567_old
│   │   ├── file3.html.13567_old
│   │   └── file4.html.13567_old
│   └── use_case_to_add_etc_2_numbers
└── vi
    ├── vim_tips_and_chearsheet
    └── vi_stuff

160 directories, 713 files
```

and I can ignore the tmp directory (for example) with `tree -I 'tmp' -L 4`

```
...
│   ├── template_multiple_files.sh
│   ├── template_one_file.sh
│   ├── template_sed.sh
│   ├── testy.sh
│   └── use_case_to_add_etc_2_numbers
└── vi
    ├── vim_tips_and_chearsheet
    └── vi_stuff

157 directories, 709 files
```

but why can I not ignore individual files such as the `_old` files with

```
tree -I 'old' -L 4
```

which *still* shows the `_old` files

```
...
│   ├── template_multiple_files.sh
│   ├── template_one_file.sh
│   ├── template_sed.sh
│   ├── testy.sh
│   ├── tmp
│   │   ├── file1.html.13567_old
│   │   ├── file2.html.13567_old
│   │   ├── file3.html.13567_old
│   │   └── file4.html.13567_old
│   └── use_case_to_add_etc_2_numbers
└── vi
    ├── vim_tips_and_chearsheet
    └── vi_stuff

160 directories, 713 files
```

I tried `'.*old'` and `'.*old$'` patterns but that didn't help.

Comment: Use shell glob patterns, not regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wildcard:

```
tree -I '*_old' -L 4
```

Reference: [man tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) (my emphasis)

> -I pattern
>
> Do not list those files that match the **wild-card** pattern.